# How to install MySQL 5.1 libraries on Ubuntu 14.04 or CentOS?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, mysql

I've got two VMs: CentOS 6.5 and Ubuntu Server 14.04.  Neither of their package management systems has the MySQL 5.1 libraries available (they both have MySQL 5.5).  I need to know how to install the MySQL 5.1 libraries on each of them.  It can be by downloading and compiling them (although I wasn't able to find 5.1 on the MySQL site) or by finding old packages that will work with either package management system (yum/apt respectively).

The underlying reason is that I need to compile a program against the 5.1 libraries.  It will not work with newer versions of MySQL.  (For complicated reasons, the program cannot be modified to work with newer versions of MySQL.)

If it makes any difference, the VMs are in Microsoft's Azure system.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://www.zulius.com/how-to/yum-install-specific-package-version/ ?

Comment: CentOS 6 already uses MySQL 5.1 by default. You don't need to do anything special there.

Comment: Michael, you're right, I misread the list.  Thanks.  In that case it's really just Ubuntu Server 14.04 that I need to be able to get MySQL 5.1 on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find what you're looking for over on [rpmfind.net](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=mysql-libs) you can find the source code on the [MySQL site](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html) I guess it builds the libs too.